# semantic UI doesn't work in django's template file

Tags: python, django, django-templates, semantic-ui

I'm writing a django website and I want to use `'Semantic UI'` for its front end. but when I add a `Semantic UI Button` to my first page in django, it only shows plain text!

the file tree of my project is like this :

```
Matab->
----Matab->
--------Templates->
--------------base.html
--------------login.html
---------settings.py
-----media->
--------css->
------------semantic.css
```

settigs.py :

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../media/').replace('\\','/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

base.html :

```
<html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/semantic.css"/>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <meta name="author" content="Navid" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="mainContent">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

login.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="ui button">hello</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is the CSS file being loaded? Can you read the file from browser?

Comment: Shouldn't you place your stylesheet in your `static` directory instead of in `media`? Static files (those stored in `media` are also static) are generally served by the webserver directly, and Django is not involved, so your webserver configuration also matters.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is with the line `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../media/').replace('\\','/')` Where is your settings.py file located in the tree?

Comment: @Bibhas : when I load the page there is this error in my terminal: GET /media/css/semantic.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2192

Comment: of course there is. Update your question with the location of settings.py

Comment: @Bibhas: settings.py is in second Matab folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in urls.py, I should insert this line :

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Please use `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` instead of `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`. And follow [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) to setup the static file directories.

Your `MEDIA_ROOT` path is wrong. Update it to this -

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'media')
```

Here `os.path.dirname(__file__)` evaluates to second Matab directory. Using `os.path.dirname()` again, takes it to First Matab directory. Then you just join it with `media`. Python automatically adds the slashes.

Comment: It didn't fix the problem! I still get the 404 error

Comment: Can you `print MEDIA_ROOT` right after the above line in settings.py?

Comment: should I use the `.replace('\\', '/')` ? I'm on windows

Comment: You shouldn't need to. Python takes care of that.

Comment: I printed it : C:/Users/Navid/PycharmProjects/Matab/media

Comment: Strange. Then try replacing it with `.replace('/'. '\\')`

Comment: now the path is : C:\Users\Navid\PycharmProjects\Matab\media but it doesn't work!

Comment: BTW, please rename MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL to STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL. Media path is onl for uploaded media like video etc. Updated the answer.